# Learning to script tools in Python and general Pen Testing

Tags: java, python

I want to learn Pen Testing and already know Java and have been learning Python and am fairly comfortable with Python syntax. I also have some knowledge on Linux and TCP/IP.
My questions are:

How can I learn to script tools in Python for Pen Testing as I have no idea where to begin, at present I have only used it to solve Top Coder problems for practice?
What can I learn in Java which I can apply towards Pen Testing?
What resources can I use to help me as an aspiring Pen Tester?

I don't want to be someone who uses someone else's tools and doesn't understand anything. I want to gain a firm foundation in Pen Testing especially the programming aspect.

Comment: Lesson 1start using the search button. This question has been asked an re-asked tons of times before.

Comment: I tried to find information related to Python though what there was said was to learn someone else's tools like scrappy, I don't I'll learn anything like this as I need to learn to code my own tools and learn what to actually do.

Comment: There are many published books on this subject. Look it up.

Comment: Read this: http://www.digininja.org/projects/breaking_in_part_1.php

Comment: Books tutorials, ... Aside from that trying to reimplement scapy will take you several years.

Comment: It's good to trying to reimplement tools but something like scapy is beyond your reach if you are still asking these type of questions.

Answer (score 6):

These books can be a good starting point:

[Violent Python: A Cookbook for Hackers, Forensic Analysts, Penetration Testers and Security Engineers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1597499579)

[Gray Hat Python: Python Programming for Hackers and Reverse Engineers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593271921)

Answer (score 2):

Look for security tube python scripting expert course. It starts with very basic and quickly ramps up to build complex scripts and tools for security

Answer (score 1):

You can also learn a lot from this practical collection of Python Web Penetration Cookbook recipes - vast variety of samples from both defensive and attacking points of view:

- [Python Web Penetration Testing Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/networking-and-servers/python-web-penetration-testing-cookbook)